# How do I convert excel file into csv file using pandas without the first row being modified?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert multiples excel files into csv files. However, when using the codes below, I am having issues with pandas modifying the values in the first row.

```
for i in path_list:
     df = pd.read_excel(i) 
     df.to_csv(i[:-5]+".csv", index = None, header=True)
```

Below is an example of how pandas modifies the first row values.

```
Excel:
1     1     1     2     2     2
21    32    3     54    6     86

CSV:
1    1.1    1.2    2    2.1    2.2
21   32     3      54   6      86
```

How can I fix this issue so that the values in the CSV file will be exactly the same as in the excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `excel` has duplicate column names. So when you read `excel` into `df`, it appends `.1, .2` after all duplicated column names.

You can do this to fix it:

```
for i in path_list:
     df = pd.read_excel(i)
     df.columns = df.columns.astype(str).str.split('.').str[0] 
     df.to_csv(i[:-5]+".csv", index = None, header=True)
```

`df.columns = df.columns.astype(str).str.split('.').str[0]` command will remove `.1, .2` from duplicate column names and will keep them the way they were in excel.

The same will be written in your `csv` also.

Comment: Hi! This worked for the header values with a decimal place. However it deletes the ones without. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @LQQ I've updated the answer. Added `astype(str)` to the command. Please check now.